# Expected string or buffer: filter html tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, filter

I can't seem to figure out the error despite looking at similar questions. Can someone point it out for me?

Error at Negative.match(parent['class']). I know I need to change from tuple type to string but where?

```
Traceback error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text2blog.py", line 197, in <module>
    print upgradeFeed(HN_RSS_FEED)

  File "text2blog.py", line 167, in upgradeFeed
    upgradedLinks.append((entry, upgradeLink(entry.link)))

  File "text2blog.py", line 147, in upgradeLink
    content = grabContent(link, html)

  File "text2blog.py", line 48, in grabContent
    if (NEGATIVE.match(parent['class'])):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The code:

```
for s in soup.findAll('script'):
    s.extract()
    
allParagraphs = soup.findAll('p')
topParent = None
    
parents = []
for paragraph in allParagraphs:
    parent = paragraph.parent
    if parent not in parents:
        parents.append(parent)
        parent.score = 0
    
        if parent.has_key('class'):
            if NEGATIVE.match(parent['class']):
                parent.score -= 50
            if POSITIVE.match(parent['class']):
                parent.score += 25
    
        if parent.has_key('id'):
            if NEGATIVE.match(parent['id']):
                parent.score -= 50
            if POSITIVE.match(parent['id']):
                parent.score += 25
    
    if parent.score == None:
        parent.score = 0
```

Comment: Did you get a traceback message? Please post it.

Comment: @tdelaney please check the edited post.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried to fix it using that but ended up screwing it up. I don't know how to do it in this context.

Comment: Is `NEGATIVE` a regular expression object (`print(NEGATIVE)` if unsure)? I'm not sure what beautifulsoup returns if a tag has more than one class. `print(parent['class'])` just before the failing line would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

See [Multi-valued attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes).

The call to `parent['class']` returns a list on my machine. The call to `.match(...)` expects a string or buffer.

Thus, you may want to pass `' '.join(parent['class'])` to `.match(...)` though the order of the values may not be the same as in the source.

Comment: Throws this - AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: The join is for the list returned by `parent['class']`, i.e.,`.match(' '.join(parent['class']))`